# SELECT if left join IS AND IS NOT ( MYSQL )?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I got one table "people".

Another one with "hobbiesConnection", and they are connected as an OneToMany.

I would like to build a search, where it is possible to search people which have a hobby and don't have a hobby.

Something like :

```
SELECT * FROM people
LEFT JOIN hobbiesConnection ON hobbiesConnection.people_id = 
hobbiesConnection.hobby_id
WHERE hobby_id = 4 AND hobby_id != 5
```

Now I get the person with the hobby 4, but I want to get an empty result, because both conditions have to fit to the person.

Does anybody have an idea how to accomplish this ?

Comment: Change where to and. Change and to or. You may need parentheses

Comment: The `WHERE` condition is satisfied only by value `4` of `hobby_id`. The `AND hobby_id != 5` part is redundant; you can safely drop it.

Comment: The join on people_id=hobby_id doesn't look right

Comment: Show the tables structure, show some input data and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your **JOIN** is not correct. The two tables should be linked with a foreign key / common column. Try the below query;

```
SELECT * FROM people
LEFT JOIN hobbiesConnection 
ON hobbiesConnection.people_id = people.people_id
And (hobbiesConnection.hobby_id = 4 AND hobbiesConnection.hobby_id != 5)
```

Comment: you edited the answer - now its corerect. I still think whole the query is wrong - consider the example data run through your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9926/5 it returns a row for people_id 1 (which has hobby 5 , so it shouldn't be here) , and for people_id = 3 (which doesn't have hobby 4 - so it also shouldn;t be here)

Answer (score -1):

use (NOT) EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT * FROM people p
WHERE TRUE
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT TRUE FROM hobbiesConnection hc 
  WHERE hc.people_id = p.people_id -- or p.id? you didnt mention
  AND hobby_id = 4
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT TRUE FROM hobbiesConnection hc 
  WHERE hc.people_id = p.people_id -- or p.id? you didnt mention
  AND hobby_id = 5
)
```

You can achieve the same using joins

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM people p
JOIN hobbiesConnection h4 ON TRUE
    AND h4.people_id = p.people_id -- or p.id? you didnt mention
    AND h4.hobby_id = 4
LEFT JOIN hobbiesConnection h5 ON TRUE
    AND h5.people_id = p.people_id -- or p.id? you didnt mention
    AND h5.hobby_id = 5
WHERE h5.id IS NULL -- or whatever column from that table
```

have a look at the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9926/4